# Is it possible to exclude parts of a javadoc comment with the gradle javadoc task?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, javadoc

Is there any possiblitiy to exclude parts of a javadoc comment for a gradle javadoc task?

e.g.:
If there is a javadoc comment like this:

```
/**
 * Describtion stuff<br>
 * 
 * more description<br>
 *
 * description for task 2
 *
 * @param something
 * @return something
 */
```

is it possible to get the output to be something like this:

```
        Task 1          |       Task 2
------------------------|-----------------------------
    Describtion stuff   |   Describtion stuff
    more description    |   more description
                        |   description for task 2
                        |                   
    Parameters:         |   Parameters:     
        something       |       something   
                        |                   
    Returns:            |   Returns:        
        something       |       something
```